# Third Party API Long Polling

Tags: c#, .net

We have Third Party API which sends a message, currently, we are able to manually make a request and get the response.

But we need to run this continuously for every 2 seconds to look up the data by passing different session id, each session id belongs to a specific user.

Consider we have about 100 individual requests with the different session id, we need to execute all 100 for every second and look up the data and send back to the user.

What is the best way to implement the message polling in c#? Can someone help with the sample?

Comment: did you try with Ajax polling?

Comment: Look in to [Reactive Extensions](http://reactivex.io/)

Comment: application wont be loaded in the browser to do the ajax polling. Its a chat app connecting salesforce to another chat app.

To get the response from the salesforce agent, we need to run the API to get the info and we need to do this via server side.

Tried doing with hangfire.io but the start time is max 1 minute and not in seconds. I am looking some kind of background worker which runs on server side.

Comment: Salesforce supports push notifications via their SDK, is it possible to use that instead of polling?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Do you have the SDK link or sample? I am looking for salesforce live agent Message Long Polling. kindly let me know.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain this is the link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_Messages.htm of the API which we need to do.

Comment: Looks like Long polling with Reactive extensions is exactly what you want. See here for some example documentation  https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/blob/master/Repository/Polling.md

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks, will check and get back if i face any problem.

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer to your question when you come up with a solution. it may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Restructured the application to microservices using service Fabric and by using Actor Model Theory.

Actors are the primitives that form the basis of the Actor model of concurrent digital computation. In response to a message that it receives, an Actor can make local decisions, create more Actors, send more messages, and designate how to respond to the next message received.